# Discord.py: update or disable discord button without editing the message

Tags: discord.py

I am writing a Discord bot which will send messages with buttons (in a View).

After sending a new message, I would like to let the buttons in the old message be disabled.
I have seen a bot which disables the button without editing the message, but all the resource I found indicate that I should edit the message to reflect the change.
I am wondering how to achieve this?

PS. I am using discord.py.

A minimal example may be like this

```
import discord

class MyView(discord.ui.View):

    @discord.ui.button(label="my button")
    async def btn_send_hint(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.Button):
        interaction.response.defer()
        button.disabled = True
```

I also tried the on_timeout function, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Even the basic examples of discord.py show that you have to edit the message. Where have you seen it?

Comment: @Dominik Hazzu pointed out that editing the view only will prevent the message being marked with the edited flag

Answer (score 0):

You necessarily need to edit the message to update its components. Only then will Discord know that that button has been disabled. Note that when you use `button.disabled = True`, this change only takes effect on your bot's variables. This does not send any information to Discord to know that that button has been disabled.
Here's an example of how you can perform this action:

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.message = None # Define a variable named message with the initial value set to None

    async def on_timeout(self):
        for child in self.children: # We need to iterate over all the buttons/selects in the View (self.children returns a list of all the Items in the View)
            child.disabled = True   # And set disabled = True to disable them
        await self.message.edit(view=self) # Now we just need to update our old message with the updated buttons

@bot.tree.command(name="foo")
async def foo(interaction):
    my_view = MyView(timeout=30.0) # We need to create an instance of this class first, so that we can set the response to the returned message object
    await interaction.response.send_message(content='on_timeout Example', view=my_view)
    # Here we're setting our `self.message` as the output message we got in return from .send_message()
    my_view.message = await interaction.original_response()
```

Adapted from [oficial faq](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-disable-all-items-on-timeout).

> Note: if you just edit the message view, it won't be marked with the *edited* flag. That must be why you think this 3rd party bot disables components without editing the message.